# Вопрос по поведению current() в PHP

Tags: php

Имеем простой код:

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    if($v == 'c') {
        return current($array);
    }
}
//Вывод: d
```

Почему выводится значение из следующей итерации, а не из текущей? Ведь по логике мы не переходили к следующей итерации, а завершаем скрипт! В документации php нет примеров этой функции с использованием циклов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php) к `foreach` четко написано

> перебирает массив, задаваемый с помощью array_expression. На каждой итерации значение текущего элемента присваивается переменной $value **и внутренний указатель массива увеличивается на единицу** (таким образом, на следующей итерации цикла работа будет происходить со следующим элементом).

Comment: Да, спасибо! Под вечер уже совсем не соображаю!